# docker.io command replaced just 'docker'

Tags: docker

The docker documents inform to use the client by the command 'docker'

```
https://docs.docker.io/introduction/working-with-docker/#working-with-the-docker-client
```

But for me I need to use 'docker.io ...'

A few months ago I played with an earlier version of docker and the command was indeed 'docker'. Can I confirm that the latest version 0.9.1 has changed the command to 'docker.io' and it is the documentation which is out of date? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Quick guess: You are on Debian or Ubuntu.

The `/usr/bin/docker` slot was already taken by a "System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications".  Hence the need to differentiate *on that platform* and use docker.io which was  conflict free.

If you want to use `docker` as a name to match the documentation, just create a shell alias or a link in `/usr/local/bin` (or somewhere else in your `$PATH`).

Comment: Thanks, indeed I am on Ubuntu 14.04. makes sense.